# books.app interface - chapters question

Tags: books

It seems to me that there are some glaring oversights in the design of the books.app application for OSX and iPhone.  I'm curious if anyone knows of a workaround, but my goal is to have the chapters listed somewhere inline to the main window (sorta like music.app does in the playlist view) so that I can easily navigate with keystrokes rather than multiple clicks with the mouse every time I want to move from chapter to chapter.  Is there something I'm missing here?

I couldn't find a setting anywhere.

I did see the key commands for chapter next/prev but this isn't what I'm looking for as I'd like to be able to glance at the application to view status (location of what chapter I'm in).

A follow-up question would be: is there any such thing as a "bookmark" in this app?!  Like a reference to a specific timepoint on a particular chapter...

Thanks for any suggestions, including a better app to use.

Comment: Maybe try using Google Docs? You can simply modify manually and automatically the table of contents

Comment: @Thinkr AFAIK that will not work for a host of file types.

Comment: Not for a host but for individual, it works